# Configure two PostgreSQL database(fail over mechanism) using Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jakarta-ee, configuration

I am using Tomcat JDBC API(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) to connect to my PostgreSQL database from Spring configuration file as shown below. I got a new requirement to configure two databases which should act as a fail over mechanism, Like When one database is down application should automatically switch back to another database.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbname?user=postgres" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="2" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    </bean>
```

Can anyone suggest how this can be achieved using Spring configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way this is done is by using virtual IP addresses (with possible forwarding), checking for activity, a shoot-the-other-node-in-the-head approach and proper failover.  Spring is exactly the wrong solution to this if you want to avoid things like data loss.

A few recommendations.

1. repmgr from 2ndquadrant will manage a lot of the process for you.
2. Use identical hardware and OS and streaming replication.
3. Use virtual IP addresses, and the like.  Use a heartbeat mechanism to trigger failover via rempgr

Then from this perspective your spring app doesn't need reconfiguring.